# iOS how to set FBFriendPickerViewController doneButton's title

Tags: facebook, ios6

there is a "doneButton" and a "cancelButton" in `FBFriendPickerViewController`, whose default title is "Done" and "Cancel". I want to customize the title:

```
FBFriendPickerViewController *friendPickerController = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
friendPickerController.title = @"invite your friend";
friendPickerController.doneButton.title = @"invite";
```

I think it should work, but it didn't. the title of doneButton was still "Done".

how can i set it? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you change the title on the Done and Cancel buttons in a `FBFriendPickerViewController`:

```
friendPickerController.cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Skip it!" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];
friendPickerController.doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invite!" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:nil];
```

Comment: The way this is written, it won't work, but it's close. You need to either just do a setTitle: on them or do what you said but put in the actions manually. Otherwise, the buttons won't do anything. Anyway, thanks; I was looking for this.